# Push X number of values of a API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the Alpha Vantage API to push the date and price of the companies, but the API gives me the values of each month for the last 20 years. How I put a "limit" on that? because I just need the values from the last 10 years or 120 values on total.

Here it's my function:

```
loadingChartPrice = async () => {
        const pointerToThis = this;
        const urlApi = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo'

        let dataChart = [];
        let priceChart = [];

        fetch(urlApi)
            .then( response => response.json())
            .then(
                function(data) {

                     for (var key in data['Monthly Adjusted Time Series']) {
                        dataChart.push(key)
                        priceChart.push(data['Monthly Adjusted Time Series'][key]['5. adjusted close']);
                      }

                    pointerToThis.setState({
                        ChartPrice: {
                            labels: dataChart.reverse(),
                            datasets: [{
                                label:'Stock Price',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.1)',
                                borderColor: 'rgba(66, 133, 244, 1)',
                                data: priceChart.reverse()
                            }]
                        }
                    })
                }
            )
    }
```

Ty for your time.

Comment: I don't see an option for querying / filtering in their API. I don't think you will find it. It must be much more efficient to have a non query able cacheable API on their part. I'd just filter out the data you don't need personally.

Comment: Try this  `data:priceChart.reverse().length=120`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution just putting "slice(0,120)" in front of the data.

```
pointerToThis.setState({
                            ChartPrice: {
                                labels: dataChart.slice(0,120).reverse(),
                                datasets: [{
                                    label:'Stock Price',
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.1)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgba(66, 133, 244, 1)',
                                    data: priceChart.slice(0,120).reverse()
                                }]
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like their API has any sort of pagination or other types of parameters. You can add a date filter by doing date math, or convert to an array and use `.slice` or a `take`-type function from a library to get the first 120 elements. (You can also get rid of your `pointerToThis` by using putting that `async` on your method to use by `await`ing the fetch :) .)

Comment: ty mate. I'll follow your tips.